# Scope of :host-context(.class) selector

Tags: angular, sass, css-selectors

According to Angular docs, the host-context() selector is searching for a match outside the scope of the component view.
[image]

So I am confused. I tried in stackblitz and I saw that there is a match even if the class is applied in the same component. Am I doing something wrong?

Attaching the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-feqh83?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:host-contexts checks class on host element same as :host and then ancestors as you know. So your tests works fine. Please don't forget that css property color is **inherited** to children.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `host-context` within the root component style itself and also the context that you are passing is something that is not the same when you are using it.

As the name suggest `host-context`, the style within this pseudo selector gets applied when it matches the parent element's context. Let's understand this with an example.

Suppose, you have a button component that you want to be themeable depending on the theme applied to it's parent element. Here the context is the parent element's class and the host-context needs to be defined in the themeable button component in a way that it applies the theme as per the parent element's context:

Example of themeable button component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'themeable-button',
  template: `
        <button class="btn btn-theme">Themeable Button</button>
  `,
  styles: [`
      :host-context(.red-theme) .btn-theme {
        background: red;
      }
      :host-context(.blue-theme) .btn-theme {
          background: blue;
      }
  `]
})
export class ThemeableButtonComponent {

}
```

As you can see the host-context pueudo class has been defined within this component's style and it takes different context (.red-theme & .blue-theme).
Now depending on the parent element where this themable component will be hosted, it's background color will be decided:

For example:

```
<div class="blue-theme"> // context here is blue-theme and hence the color of this button will be blue
  <themeable-button></themeable-button>
</div>

<div class="red-theme">
  <themeable-button></themeable-button>
</div>


<div class="no-theme"> // This won't have any color as no-theme is not a valid context defined in themeable button component.
      <themeable-button></themeable-button>
</div>
```

Check this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hb5bfe?file=src/app/app.component.html), where I have this example.